# Types of Variables Python

Tags: python, variables

```
x = 4
name = "Josh"
y = 3.2
guess = True
stuff = ["guitar", "bed"]
days = {"Monday":"favourite", "Friday": "least favourite"}
jay = (3, 9)
```

I am learning Python and am currently learning about the various types of variables. The current exercise asks me to choose what type of variable is being defined. The options include: Array, Boolean, decimal, dictionary, float, integer, list, string, tuple. Can someone  look over my answers and tell me what y is

- x is a string
- name is a string
- y is a decimal/float
- guess is a boolean
- stuff is a list
- days is a dictionary
- jay is a tuple

Comment: No research effort -1

Comment: Try this: `type(3.2)` or `type(y)`.

Comment: "Can someone look over my answers and tell me what y is"? Well, looking over your answers, it says "y is a decimal/float". So, "decimal/float". That was easy, I didn't even need a regexp. :P

Comment: There is no minimal understanding of the problem, nor any research effort on the part of the OP

Comment: Meanwhile, variables don't have types in Python. _Values_ have types. You can write `x = 4` and then right after that write `x = 'abc'`, because `x` is not an integer variable, it's just a variable, and it can hold anything.

Comment: By the why, whoever is assigning a problem to a rank novice and confusing them with types like "decimal" and "Array" (presumably `decimal.Decimal` and `array.array`?) is being at least silly and possibly cruel. Why not make them distinguish between `unicode` and `bytes`, throw in a question about `{}` after showing a bunch of sets, and then trick them with a type like `function` whose name isn't accessible so you have to go digging in the `types` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 4  # this is an int (an integer)
name = "Josh"  # string
y = 3.2  # float (decimal point number)
guess = True  # bool (boolean)
stuff = ["guitar", "bed"]  # list
days = {"Monday":"favourite", "Friday": "least favourite"}  # dictionary (a hashmap, in computational-theory speak)
jay = (3, 9)  # tuple (works like a list, but you can't change the elements)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try it out...

```
>>> y = 3.2
>>> type(y)
<type 'float'>
>>>
```

The [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function tells you exactly what you are asking.

Here are a [list and description of the built in types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html).